# django apply widget for all fields

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget, django-widget-tweaks

Is there a way to apply css class to **ALL** fields instead of doing the following for every single field.

**forms.py**

```
class UserColorsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserColors
        exclude = ('userid',)
        widgets = {
            'text_color': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'color'}),
            'background_color': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'color'}),
            ... 10 more
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UserColorsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for field in self.fields: 
        field.wiget.attrs['class'] = 'color'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This one works: for field in self:
  field.field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'color'

Comment: that's strange, I'm pretty sure the proposed solution is the correct one. What error do you get?

Comment: self.fields iterates over fields' strings values. self iterates over unbound fields. I'm using django 1.7.

Comment: This one didn't work for me. I did `for key in self.fields.keys(): self.fields[key].attrs.update({'class': 'my-class'})`, and it worked

Answer (score 4):

To update Mihai's answer, the way is:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(YourForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for field in self.fields:
        self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'myfieldclass'})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to iterate the form fields:

```
css1 = {'class': 'color', }
css2 = {'class': 'nocolor', }
class UserColorsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserColorsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for key, value in self.fields.iteritems():
            if key in ['field1', 'field2', ...]: # You can define a 
                # subset of fields in a list to selectively apply css classes, 
                # OR just iterate and apply to everything 
                # (take out the if-else statement)
                self.fields[key].widget.attrs.update(css1)
            else:
                self.fields[key].widget.attrs.update(css2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of the fields you want. Then create a function that returns a dictionary using the fields as keys. Lastly, you set the Meta.widgets to call the function you have created.

```
fields_you_want = [
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'other_names',
        ] 


def get_widget_dictionary():

    keys = fields_you_want

    values = [ forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}) for key in keys ]
    result = dict(zip(keys, values))
    return result


class UserColorsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserColors
        widgets = get_widget_dictionary()
```